# Sort hash having duplicate values in ascending order of keys

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash that looks like this:

```
{"P1"=>108, "P6"=>50, "P3"=>50, "P5"=>40, "P2"=>40, "P4"=>40}
```

This is already sorted in the descending order of value.

I want the output below, where the original ordering (by value descending) is maintained, but the elements with the same values are sorted in ascending order of keys (for e.g., `P3` comes before `P6`).

```
{"P1"=>108, "P3"=>50, "P6"=>50, "P2"=>40, "P4"=>40, "P5"=>40 }
```

Any pointers of approaching this in a simple way would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple conditions for sort, use an array.

```
{"P1"=>108, "P6"=>50, "P3"=>50, "P5"=>40, "P2"=>40, "P4"=>40}
.sort_by{|k, v| [-v, k]}.to_h
```

Comment: @sawa: Thanks for your answer. Would it be possible for you to explain your approach in a little more detail, especially the `[-v, k]` part or else if you could point me to some example article that explains the same, even that would help. I did have a look at [sort_by](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-sort_by-21) documentation, but that didn't help much.

Comment: Each class has its own definition of `<=>`, which is used in sort. For arrays, its elements are compared from the first one. If they are not a tie, then that would be the result of comparison. If there is a tie, then the next elements are compared. And so on. The `-v` is using the fact that the value is a numeral. By negating a numeral, it has the same effect as descending sort.

Comment: @sawa Please excuse my late reply. I understood from your explanation that -v will consider to arrange the hash values in the descending order, but I'm not very clear with how does the sorting work when the hash keys have the same value. In such a scenario, are the key value pairs sorted in the default ascending order of the keys? If yes, what part of your code answer tells ruby to do so?. Also, out of curiosity if I want to sort the key value pairs that have the same element value in the descending order but retain the original descending order of values how can I achieve this? Thank you.